# Why doesn’t { preventScroll: true } work?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` field and focus it via `focus({preventScroll:true})`. However, Chrome on Android still scrolls to put it into focus. What could be the reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how many rows your textarea has! If the number of rows exceed the height of your viewport, Chrome still scrolls. However, if you have a small textarea, that is completely visible within the viewport, no scroll occurs.